# Why am I getting this error member access within null pointer of type 'ListNode'

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 };
```

```
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* removeNthFromEnd(ListNode* head, int n) {
        int count=0;
        ListNode* temp2 = head; 
        ListNode* temp1 = head; 
        ListNode* temp = head; 
        while (temp != NULL) 
        { 
          ++count; 
          temp = temp->next; 
        }
        
        
        int i=1;
        
        while(i!=(n-count) && temp1->next!=NULL && temp2->next!=NULL)
        {
            i++;
            temp2=temp2->next;
            temp1=temp1->next;
        }
       
        temp2=temp1->next;      //move temp2 to next
        
        temp2->val=temp1->val;   //put val of temp2 to temp---so val erased
        
        temp1->next=temp2->next;    //adjust link
        
        delete(temp2);      //free
        
        return head;
        
    }
};
```

I got this error

> member access within null pointer of type 'struct ListNode'

I did apply null checks, but I'm not able to detect the error. It's about "Remove Nth Node From End of List".

Comment: What is the purpose of the first loop?

Comment: If `n` is the number-from-end, would the landing place be `count-n` not `n-count` ? E.g. `while(i!=(n-count) && ...` shouldn't that be `while(i!=(count-n) &&  ...` ?

Comment: Consider storing `count` somewhere where `head` is being kept.

Comment: I recommend you start by creating a small simple linked list, and use pencil and paper to also draw it (for visualization). Use small boxes for the nodes and other variables, and arrows for pointers and links in the list. Then use a *debugger* to step through the code statement by statement. Follow along on the paper, and erase and redraw pointers (arrows) as you modify them in your program. Will the visualization make sense when the code is finished or hits the problem?

Comment: If `head` is null, and `n` is any value other than 1, the 2nd `while` loop would be accessing `temp1->next` and `temp2->next` via null pointers. As would the code after the 2nd loop, regardless of the value of `n`. So, after the 1st `while` loop, if `count` is 0, you should return null immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rethink or clearly define what "nth" means.

What about the corner cases? Like -1 or 0 or count-1 or count or count+1.

After that, please add some validation of the parameter "n".

You have also one major problem in the code. You mixed up `(count - n)` with `0(n - count)`

A potential solution with assumptions on what nth means could be:

```
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode* next;
    ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x, ListNode* next) : val(x), next(next) {}
};

class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* removeNthFromEnd(ListNode* head, int n) {
        int count = 0;
        ListNode* temp2 = head;
        ListNode* temp1 = head;
        ListNode* temp = head;
        while (temp != nullptr)
        {
            ++count;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        if ((count > 0) && (n>0) && ((count - n) > 0)) {
            int i = 1;

            while (i != (count - n) && temp1->next != nullptr && temp2->next != nullptr)
            {
                i++;
                temp2 = temp2->next;
                temp1 = temp1->next;
            }
            temp2 = temp1->next;      //move temp2 to next

            //temp2->val = temp1->val;   //put val of temp2 to temp---so val erased

            temp1->next = temp2->next;    //adjust link

            delete temp2;      //free

            return head;
        }
    }
};
int main() {

    // Build linked list
    ListNode *n5 = new ListNode(5);
    ListNode* n4 = new ListNode(4, n5);
    ListNode* n3 = new ListNode(3, n4);
    ListNode* n2 = new ListNode(2, n3);
    ListNode* n1 = new ListNode(1, n2);
    ListNode* n0 = new ListNode(0, n1);

    Solution solution;
    solution.removeNthFromEnd(n0,6);
}
```